# StateT[Either] with failover in Scalaz

Tags: scala, scalaz

I'm trying to create some kind of `failover` behaviour in a composition of `"scalaz-core"%"7.2.14"` StateT monads.

The StateT monad wraps around EitherT thus it's a monad transformer:

```
type Error = String
type ErrOrT[T] = Error \/ T
type State[T] = StateT[ErrOrT, String, T]
```

With these types everything works great - I can leverage the power of `Either` plus `State`. I have short-circuit in case of error and can stack my States in one monadic composition:

```
def func1: State[Int] = ???
def func2: State[Int] = ???
def func3: State[Int] = ???

val stateMonad = for {
  res1 <- func1
  res2 <- func2
  res3 <- func3
} yield res3
```

In addition I want to create something like `tryWithFailover` method. It returns original `State[T]` monad or fallback `State[T]` monad in case of inner `EitherT`contains left:

```
def tryWithFailover[T](run: State[T])(failover: Error => State[T]): State[T] = ???
```

So the resulting chain would be:

```
val stateMonad = for {
  res1 <- func1
  res2 <- tryWithFailover(func2)(err => failover)
  res3 <- func3
} yield res3
```

If the `failover` was just a value it would not be a problem. I can use `mapT/mapK` methods which have an access to inner monad and thus able to check whether the result left or right. In case of left I can recreate inner monad with `fallback` value. But it's not a value, it's a monad itself and I need something like `flatMapT`.

Do I miss something, any thought on how it might be done? Failover util function will help me a lot, don't want to break the chain in the middle with explicit `run` call.

---

**UPD:**

Abovementioned failover with value might be like this:

```
def tryWithFailover[T](run: State[T])(failover: Error => T): State[T] = {
  for {
    lockedState <- State(st => (st, st))
    result <- run.mapT[ErrOrT, T, String] {
      case ok@ \/-(_) => ok
      case -\/(error) => \/-((lockedState, failover(error)))
    }
  } yield result
}
```

---

**UPD2:**

Bad implementation which breaks overall monadic chain with `run` in the middle:

```
def tryWithFailover[T](run: State[T])(failover: Error => State[T]): State[T] = {
  for {
    lockedState <- State(st => (st, st))
    result <- run.mapT[ErrOrT, T, String] {
      case ok@ \/-(_) => ok
      case -\/(error) => failover(error).run(lockedState)
    }
  } yield result
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some considerations I came to the conclusion that mentioned approach is not bad:

```
def tryWithFailover[T](run: State[T])(failover: Error => State[T]): State[T] = {
  for {
    lockedState <- State(st => (st, st))
    result <- run.mapT[ErrOrT, T, String] {
      case ok@DRight(_) => ok
      case DLeft(error) => failover(error).run(lockedState)
    }
  } yield result
}
```

May be someday somebody will correct my answer.